# rendering form fields normally vs rendering using a function

Tags: reactjs, function, render

there are two ways i am rendering form fields

first way is directly putting them inside a render

form.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface FormProps {
}

export interface FormState {
    personal: any
}

class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, FormState> {
    constructor(props: FormProps) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            personal: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
            }
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event: any) => {
        let personal = { ...this.state.personal };
        personal[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ personal })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>first name</h1>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.personal.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <h1>last name</h1>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.personal.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

the other way

form.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface FormProps {
}

export interface FormState {
    personal: any
}

class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, FormState> {
    constructor(props: FormProps) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            personal: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
            }
        }
    }

    count = 0;
    handleChange = (event: any) => {
        let personal = { ...this.state.personal };
        personal[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ personal })
    }

    renderFields = () => {

        this.count++;
        console.log('render fields call count = ', this.count);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>first name</h1>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.personal.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <h1>last name</h1>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.personal.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.renderFields()
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

issue here is render fields being called on every state change and that is understandable but will this affect my performance

what i am going to do next is turn a json schema into form
checking what type of field it is and accordingly create the input field and many more things
example json is

```
"personal":{
"fields":[
  {
    "label":"name",
    "type":"text"
  },
  {
    "label":"id",
    "type":"number"
   }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont't actually hamper performance. Because there won't be actual dom manipulation if form's DOM attribute has not changed. To enhance more you can have pure component. To make custom formField where type and label can be changed. Have a custom form field component.